# Showing that $|\phi(\mathcal{M})| = |\phi(\mathcal{N})|$ if $\phi(\mathcal{M}) \Subset M^n$ and $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\phi \in L$ define a finite set $X$ in the $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$.  Show that in every $\mathcal{N}$ elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal{M}$, the set defined by $\phi$ has the same power as $X$.

1. Let $n$ denote the number of free variables of $\phi$.  That is, let $\phi \in L_n$
2. Then $X = \phi(\mathcal{M}) = \{a^n \in M^n : \mathcal{M} \models \phi(\overline{a})\}$ and is a finite subset of $M^{n}$.  That is, $X \Subset M^n$.  Denote $|X| = k \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. Let $\mathcal{N}$ be an arbitrary $L$-structure s.t. $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$.  Then, by definition, $Th(\mathcal{M}) = Th(\mathcal{N})$.
4. Let $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| = Y$

   $\fbox{WANT:}$ $X = |\phi(\mathcal{M})| = |\phi(\mathcal{N})| = Y$

Now this would be easy to show if $\mathcal{M}$ were isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$.  But we cannot assume that unless $\mathcal{M}$ is finite.  I'm not sure how then to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property "there are exactly $k$ elements of $M^n$ satisfying $\phi$" is equivalent to a first-order sentence. Since it is true in $\mathcal{M}$, it is also true in $\mathcal{N}$.

This reduces the problem to identifying this sentence. Hint: Do you know how to write down a sentence expressing that there exist exactly $k$ things in the universe? Can you adapt this to realizations of $\phi$?

Comment: I can't get the formatting right in this comment box, but I believe this is how you do it in the case that $\phi \in L_1$:

$$\exists x_1, \ldots , \exists x_n \left[(\phi(x_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \phi(x_n)) \wedge ((x_1 \ne x_2) \wedge \ldots \wedge (x_{n-1} \ne x_n)) \wedge (\forall y \phi(y) \rightarrow \phi(x_1) \vee \ldots \vee \phi(x_n)) \right]$$

But what about for $\phi \in L_n$ for $n > 1$?

Comment: The sentence you wrote down isn't quite right. At the end, you mean $\phi(y)\rightarrow \lor_i(y=x_i)$. The exact same idea works for $L_n$, you just need to figure out how to express "$x = y$" when $x$ and $y$ are tuples instead of single variables. But that's easy - two tuples are equal just when each pair of components are equal. Formatting looks fine to me, by the way.

Comment: Whoops -- my apologies.

Comment: No problem - I don't care about the reputation, it's just nice to have fewer "unanswered" questions floating around.